# Make tmux tabs arrange more like traditional tabs

Tags: tmux

Tmux is a great piece of software, which almost replaced me my terminal "terminator", especially with it's `<bindkey>-z` in recent versions.

The main annoyance I have with tmux is that whenever I close a window(tab), say #2, all other tabs like #3 keep being there. And when I create a new window(tab), it stores it on place of #2.

What I'd like to get is more traditional behavior, like web-browsers and other tab-based software does: when you close tab, fill free cells by moving everything from right to left. When you create tab, create it on right. Then, if I'll want to place window(tab) somewhere, I can ask tmux to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using tmux 1.7, you can use the `renumber-window` option:

> **renumber-windows [on | off]**
>                      If on, when a window is closed in a session, automatically renumber the other windows in numerical order.  This
>                      respects the base-index option if it has been set.  If off, do not renumber the windows.

Setting this in your `.tmux.conf` like so:

```
set -g renumber-windows on
```

means that closing window #2 will renumber window #3 to #2 and opening a new window will place it at #3.